# Remove all pressed keydown events

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a plugin (sort of lightbox/tour/gallery) which runs with the click of a button, and when the button has been click the user can navigate thru the plugin with the use of the keyboard keys(left and right for prev/next) but when the plugin comes to the end(last image) and the user keeps on pushing the right arrow key when the user clicks the button and the plugin runs again the previous registered key presses will be fired.

Is there a way to clear all registered keypresses like cleaning the chache?

// keydown part

```
  $('body').on('keydown', function(e){

      /**   
      * Space key.
      **/   
      if(e.keyCode == 32){

          //run code

      }

      /**   
      * Arrow left key.
      **/                               
      if(e.keyCode == 37){

         //run code

      }

      /**   
      * Arrow right key.
      **/
      if(e.keyCode == 39){

          //run code

      }

  });
```

Answer (score 3):

As you correctly used `on()` to attach the event handler, you can use [`off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) to detach it. If you do not pass a function to it, it will remove all event handlers for that event:

```
$("body").off( "keydown" );
```

As you are doing this on the `<body>` tho, this is a bit heavy-handed, as you may end up removing other keypress handlers which aren't part of your plugin. A better option would be to pass the specific function to `off()` so you only remove that handler. You can structure it something like this:

```
// IIFE to encapsulate plugin variables
(function() {

    function keyDownHandler(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 39) {
            // code...
        }    
    }

    // attach the handler
    body.on('keydown', keyDownHandler);

    // some function to handle moving through the carousel
    function showImage() {
        if(endOfCarousel) {
            // remove the handler
            body.off('keydown', keyDownHandler);
        }
    }

})();
```

By the way `unbind()` mentioned in the other answers is used for events attached with `bind()`, and is less preferred.

Comment: I do like this, not sure why I didn't come up with this one...thanks.I But how do you pass the parameters like the e?

Comment: It is the same as you are already doing, you are just passing a reference to the function in the `on('keydown')` instead of writing it inside directly.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Jquery 
It has some function to bind or unbind events
It requires the event name, which you want to unsubscribe. 
I would advice to have a look at [this link](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) for better understanding. 
You may use it something like this

```
if(end of the carosel){
$(this).unbind(your desired event)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$( "#body").unbind( "keydown" );
```

[Official documentation](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)